# Which template, frameworks do you use when developing a website for front-end edit?

Tags: joomla-3.x, t3-framework, zoo

We have created multiple Joomla website, from smaller projects, to big ones. There was always the idea of implementig neu things and trying them out so we can come to an basic project, where we could always start from.
Last thing  i was using is T3 Framework, ZOO application builder and also Widgetkit from Yootheme and i must say i kinda got the best form that we wanted.

But now still, i can´t say its the best solution. Widgetkit from yootheme has no front-end edit and ZOO has also so manj limitations on front-end.

All customers want front-end edit and we always come to an end when it comes to that. I just can´t get the right recipe for all. Its never a project where fron-end is 100%.

And yes, sometimes is fron-end edit a bit dull and not so inovative as for some application and extension, but unfortunately everyone is expecting that.

What would you say is the best combination of template, modules and frameworks that you use and would you recomend that allows fron-end edit for everything possible? For galeries, content, blog, news,...

Comment: Good question for discussion, but not sure it is that good for JSE, as it tends to be open for opinionated answers and answers that will be listing this and that extensions -- It's a question for a forum maybe, where everyone can talk about his experiences or preferences, but here ?? But maybe I m wrong- so other JSE members may think differently...

Comment: @FFrewin I tend to agree with you. It might be salvageable if it were narrowed down to pros and cons of a specific framework or the suitability of frameworks to a specific task.