# How do you start new project design implementation?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, responsive-web-design

You choose the framework and extension for your new website project and actually all is set. The designer sends you some Photohop files with new design.

I tried to find online some instruction what are the best first steps to implement the design in Joomla, but i didn't find any.

How do you start your project? Do you first make a plain HTML site with all the features needed (with JS and CSS stuff) or do you start implementing  the design directly to a Joomla template?

Comment: Look, we are here to help, but this site has limitations about what is on-topic. We also ask that you do some research before posting a question -- because the web is teeming with great information. Somebody might be happy to write out a list of steps, but it's my opinion that your question is Too Broad and Opinion-based. Please take the JSE tour and earn your Informed badge. Google.. https://www.joomla.org/about-joomla/getting-started.html and https://websitesetup.org/build-website-with-joomla/ and http://docs.joomlabamboo.com/getting-started/first-steps-in-building-your-joomla-3-website.html

Comment: Remember what @Ffrewin told you nearly 2 years ago... https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/18885/12352

Answer (score 1):

I like to use zurb foundation as my base, and as Joomla 3.X is coupled with bootstrap – this is my process:

1. design homepage in photoshop/XD
2. build a custom static html site using foundation (eg homepage). I prefer this approach as I don't need to think about php or entering content. I have started to use avocode to speed it up the XD to code conversion.
3. Then I start to build the joomla template from scratch - I have studied or used as a base:

   - https://github.com/Lyquix/tpl_lyquix
   - https://github.com/gsuez/master-bootstrap-3
   - https://github.com/Bloggerschmidt/Blank
   - https://joomlafuture.com/
   - https://github.com/RemcoJanssen/foundation6-template
   - https://github.com/robwent/joomlapure
   - https://github.com/construct-framework/bootstruct/blob/develop/elements/logic.php
     to work out what I want - but now have my own base.
4. Work out the module positions that you want in your template:
   http://docs.joomla.org/Module_positions - you could have module positions for example:

   - header
   - left
   - right
5. Put the module positions in your .xml template file
6. I use JS CSS Control plugin to ensure that bootstrap/jquery etc are removed:
   https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/js-css-control/
   as some components force bootstrap inside
7. Use Joomla overrides for components/modules in template:
   http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core
8. Use a CCK - so the client doesn't have to worry about code. I like FLEXIcontent.